# problem on lit with the routing (window.location)

Tags: routes, vaadin, window.location, lit-element, lit

good morning. I'm using lit-element and I'm trying to implement the function:
`window.location.href = "/component`
but it doesn't work, it takes me to a page that says: not found
I'm using vaadin router

Any idea?
thanks

complete code

```
    if (this.ArrayNombres.includes(this.name)) {
      window.location.href ('/component');
    } else {
      alert("name not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
Router.go(`/component`);
```